# How to reset node information in Bitcoin Core?

Tags: bitcoin-core, nodes, peers

I think I've just put the wrong node IPs through console and I forgot all the IPs.

I would like to reset all the node information to the initial.

Should I just delete peers.dat?

Comment: What do you mean by "reset node information"? Do you mean to have Bitcoin Core forget all of the nodes it knows about and redo peer discovery?

Comment: @AndrewChow I want to return to the initial state because I've put wrong chain's IP through console by command 'addnode'. I am worrying about syncing error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reset the peer database to the initial state, stop Bitcoin Core, delete the peers.dat file, and start Bitcoin Core again.